# How to copy content of a menu popup?

Tags: macos, safari, popups

I want to copy "Recent Inbox messages" from the popup below. Is it possible? The thing is, when I move mouse to hover it,  popup disappears. I am using Safari 7 on Mac.

[image: Mouseover button providing tooltip/popup message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an extension like Firebug, you can easily find the message in the code. If you right-click the mailbox icon and select 'Inspect element with Firebug' you automatically get dropped to the relevant code:

[image]

From there you can copy the text. Keep in mind that this just works for StackExchange sites and might be implemented differently on other websites.

Comment: I use Safari, but it is still wonderful, as there is such thing as "Inspect object" (not sure however about translation, it is last option when right-click on some object on page). +1 for that.